# How to use pipe | in postman params

Tags: rest, api, postman

On postman, I want to hit a GET API, where I want to pass a param **channelCategory** : **News|Movies**, which is an array of strings. To separate those strings we are using pipe |. After hitting the API I am getting an empty response. So what I can do to get the response?

This API works perfectly in SOAPUI tool.

I tried using the below combinations but was not successful.
News"|"Movies
News%7CMovies

Please note : And I can't use comma instead of pipe.

Comment: I have an API using 'or' to filter response and in the corresponding cURL request it shows as %2C. Could you try with News%2CMovies ?

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks for the help  A.Joly

Comment: :)  great ! I'll write the answer with as much info as possible to share it with the community ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some more information that may be useful around this subject:

You may use operators in request expression, depending on if you want to combine different values for a single argument or combine different arguments.
In my case, I use variables for filtering an argument named 'tags' in my collection to do a 'OR' for a same argument :

```
(|(tags=CONFIGURATION)(tags=EXPLOITATION))
```

which translates as

```
(%7C(tags%3DCONFIGURATION)(tags%3DEXPLOITATION))
```

In fact, I realize that your initial translation with %7C was correct, but you probably misused it (%3D corresponds to '=')

The other combination I suggested you is more related to a list of arguments that are to be excluded from the response and It seems to have the same usage (except that there is no argument mentioned, which is not a problem in my case, and yours). 
My requests looks like this:

```
GET http:// .... /?filter={{filter}}&exclude={{exclude}}&expand={{expand}}
```

with

```
filter=(|(tags=CONFIGURATION)(tags=EXPLOITATION))
exclude=[{"key":"exclude","value":"href,metadata,name,arguments"}]
expand=id
```

and is translated, in cURL, like this:

```
'http: ....  ?filter=(%7C(tags%3DCONFIGURATION)(tags%3DEXPLOITATION))&exclude=href%2Cmetadata%2Cname%2Carguments&expand=id'  ....
```

to do a 'OR' you could probably try `(|(channelCategory=News)(channelCategory=Movies))` with success though the other form (as a list) seem to fulfill your needs.